# Ошибка при сборке приложения - файл используется другим процессом

Tags: c#, visual-studio

**Любая программа на visual studio c# не компилируется выводит такое оишбка**

1>------ Сборка начата: проект: MyWinForms, Конфигурация: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4194,5): warning MSB3026: не удалось скопировать "obj\Debug\MyWinForms.exe" в "bin\Debug\MyWinForms.exe". Повторная попытка 1 начнется через 1000 мс. Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "bin\Debug\MyWinForms.exe", так как этот файл используется другим процессом. "MyWinForms (5616)" блокирует этот файл

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4194,5): error MSB3021: не удалось скопировать файл "obj\Debug\MyWinForms.exe" в "bin\Debug\MyWinForms.exe". Процесс не может получить доступ к файлу "bin\Debug\MyWinForms.exe", так как этот файл используется другим процессом.
========== Сборка: успешно: 0, с ошибками: 1, без изменений: 0, пропущено: 0 ==========

**Сказали что проблема в EFS UI Aplication(Шифрующая файловая система-архивация ключа шифровании файлов), но не знаю как это исправить. Помогите пожалуйста!**

Comment: У вас просто приложение уже запущено, закройте его, или убейте из task manager

Comment: @PashaPash у меня закрыто первый раз запускается но когда что то изменяю в программе опять выходит такое ошибка!

Comment: Значит по закрытию у вас не завершается процесс. Может вы окно прячете, а не выходите из программы. Может потоки запускаете без указания isbackground - кто его знает. Берите отладчик, debug, attach to process, и ищите что у вас там висит после закрытия программы

Comment: Откройте диспетчер задач, возможно там оно висит. Вам даже id блокирующего процесса подсказывает в тексте ошибки. Его также можно увидеть в Диспетчере задач.

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемый didar,

в комментариях Вам дают правильные советы. У Вас явно не завершается процесс, этот процесс использует exe-файл и поэтому Студия не может этот файл перезаписать при сборке.

Но если Вам подойдет временное решение - то в студии есть такие pre build tasks: это свойств проекта, которое говорит, какие команды надо выполнить перед сборкой. Туда можно вписать команду, которая "пристреливает" Ваше запущенное приложение.

Мне в комментариях PashaPash подсказывает, что это можно сделать командой `taskkill /im some.exe`.

я обычно в случае, когда надо много всего делать из командной строки - устанавливал пакет [sysinternals](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite), который добавит в систему команду pskill. Её - с именем Вашего приложения - тоже можно включить в pre-build tasks.

А вообще, конечно, надо искать, почему не завершается процесс.

Comment: taskkill /im some.exe

Comment: @PashaPash - круто, привыкаешь к одному и не знаешь про другое :-) Спасибо!